# «Я вся чешусь, не пойму, от чего». Нужны ли две запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении «Я вся чешусь, не пойму, от чего». Стоит ли ставить запятую перед «от чего»?
Пример из Розенталя: «Я бы тоже желал знать почему» подходит для непостановки запятой?
«От чего» можно написать раздельно, т. е. от чего конкретно, блох или там других насекомых?

Answer (score 2):

***Я вся чешУсь, не пойму отчегО.***

1. Здесь желательно выбрать вариант без второй запятой, что связано со структурой предложения (его сложно разделить на три части).

Сравнить: ***Я вся чешУсь, только никак не поймУ,  отчегО.*** При распространении предложения можно поставить еще одно ударение и обособить последнее слово, то есть возможны **оба варианта** (авторский выбор логического подчеркивания).

**Правило Розенталя** допускает оба варианта http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137

П.4. Между главной и следующей за ней придаточной частью сложноподчиненного предложения запятая не ставится:

(3) если придаточная часть состоит **из одного союзного слова** (относительного местоимения или наречия): Я бы тоже желал знать почему (Л. Т.);

В условиях контекста **возможна постановка запятой** или тире и перед одиночным союзным словом: Что же надо делать? Научите, что — усиленное логическое выделение местоимения;

2. **О раздельном написании предлога ОТ:** *чесаться от чего.*

Желательно слитное написание, раздельное письмо выглядит **разговорным**. Такой вариант возможен в тех случаях, которые указаны в словаре (от какой-то **болезни**).

ЧЕСАТЬСЯ, нсв.  2. Испытывать зуд; зудеть. Болячки чесались. **Ч. от сладкого**, от прививки (о проявлении аллергии или другого кожного заболевания).